# How do I pass Rails5 flash notification to toastr in a form_for with remote: true without reloading the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, toastr

I am building a basic CRUD app and I have a form_for that is set up for ajax with remote: true. The form works, as do the notifications, but I can't get it integrate with toastr. Essentially, this is showing me I am having trouble understanding how flash is actually working.

I've worked through getting like 95% of the way there. I am just having problems with this last step of getting the handoff to toastr.

Here is my layouts/_flash partial

```
#flash_messages
  - flash.each do |f|
    -type = f[0].to_s
    = javascript_tag do
      toastr["#{type}"]("#{f[1]}")
```

My status controller action

```
def create
     @status = Status.new(status_params)
     if @status.save"
         flash[:success] = "status created!"
       respond_to do |format|
         format.js
       end
     else
       redirect_to :back
     end
   end
```

My form_for

```
= form_for(current_user.statuses.build, remote: true) do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :media_id, :value => media.id
  =f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
  =f.hidden_field :media_type, :value => media.media_type
  %label.label= f.label :completion_status, 'Set Status'
  .field.has-addons
    .control
      .select
        = f.select :completion_status, options_for_select(["current", "completed", "future", "abandoned"])
    .control
      = f.submit "Save!", :class => "button is-primary"
```

and my controller action.js.haml file

```
$("#item_#{ @media.id }").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'shared/media_status/destroy_status', :locals => { :media => @media }))}");
- flash.each do |type, message|
  $("#flash_messages").html("#{type}: #{message.html_safe?}")
```

I'm expecting this to render the toastr notification, but instead I just get a text flash. When I reload the page, the toastr notification renders correctly.

I've worked on this a lot and I am not very smart. I feel like I am just missing something dumb here.

Comment: please check my ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390312/rails-flash-on-ajax-request-without-reload
I hope this will work for you

Comment: Oh. My. God. Thank you! The answer you provided there totally worked. I don't know how long I struggled with this. It was annoying the hell out of me. I don't know if it is proper etiquette for this site, but can you just copy/paste that answer so I can accept it? I don't know how I missed that answer in the search.