# Rails flash on ajax request (Without reload)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im building sort of a facebook clone, and one of the requirements for the project is being able to "like" posts.

I have the liking down, (im also using devise fwiw on the user authentication). But when I try to flash that a user has already liked a post (since you can't like more than once) nothing happens.

My controller code:

```
 def like
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    puts post
    like = post.likes.new(user_id: current_user.id)
    if like.save
      #nothing for now
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "You have already liked that post"
    end
  end
```

It works by being on a users "homepage" and going through all of their posts and having a "like" option on each one. (Liking does work, but figured it was worth noting).

If I just do `flash` it'll work if I refresh the page, but currently does nothing right now.

The "Like" link looks like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<p>
  <%= post.content %>
</p>
<%= link_to "Like", like_path(@user, post_id: post), remote: true, method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, you can mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails there is one gem for ajax call flash messages
[Toaster gem](https://github.com/tylergannon/toastr-rails)

Create one method in `application_helper.rb`

```
def custom_bootstrap_flash
  flash_messages = []
  flash.each do |type, message|
    type = 'success' if type == 'notice'
    type = 'error'   if type == 'alert'
    text = "
      <script>
        $(function () {
          toastr.#{type}(\"#{message}\");
        });
      </script>
    "
    flash_messages << text.html_safe if message
  end
  flash_messages.join("\n").html_safe
end
```

Include it in your layout `application.html.erb`

```
<%= custom_bootstrap_flash %>
```

And in your `action.js.erb` show toast message using toaster method

```
toastr.success('Success.')
toastr.error('error')
```

I hope this what you are looking.

Answer (score 1):

The flash method on rails shows only on successful redirect. If you want to show the message on the same page it would be better to show the message using JS.